# How can I run beta gcloud component like "gcloud beta artifacts docker images scan" within Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build, beta

I am trying to include the Container Analyis API [link](https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/ods-quickstart) in a Cloud Build pipeline.This is a beta component and with command line I need to install it first:

```
gcloud components install beta local-extract
```

then I can run the on demand container analyis (if the container is present locally):

```
gcloud beta artifacts docker images scan ubuntu:latest
```

My question is how I can use component like **beta local-extract** within Cloud Build ?

I tried to do a fist step and install the missing componentL

```
## Update components
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['components', 'install', 'beta', 'local-extract', '-q']
  id: Update component
```

but as soon as I move to the next step the update is gone (since it is not in the container)

I also tried to install the component and then run the scan using (& or ;) but it is failling:

```
## Run vulnerability scan
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud'
  args: ['components', 'install', 'beta', 'local-extract', '-q', ';', 'gcloud', 'beta', 'artifacts', 'docker', 'images', 'scan', 'ubuntu:latest', '--location=europe']

  id: Run vulnaribility scan
```

and I get:

```
Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud
ERROR: (gcloud.components.install) unrecognized arguments:
  ;
  gcloud
  beta
  artifacts
  docker
  images
  scan
  ubuntu:latest
  --location=europe (did you mean '--project'?)
  To search the help text of gcloud commands, run:
  gcloud help -- SEARCH_TERMS
```

so my question are:

1. how can I run "gcloud beta artifacts docker images scan ubuntu:latest" within Cloud Build ?
2. bonus: from the previous command how can I get the "scan" output value that I will need to pass as a parameter to my next step ? (I guess it should be something with --format)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try the `cloud-sdk` docker image:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-sdk-docker

The Cloud Build team (implicitly?) recommends it:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/tree/master/gcloud

With the `cloud-sdk-docker` container you can change the entrypoint to `bash` pipe `gcloud` commands together.  Here is an (ugly) example:

https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/functions-framework-cpp/blob/d3a40821ff0c7716bfc5d2ca1037bcce4750f2d6/ci/build-examples.yaml#L419-L432

As to your bonus question.  Yes, `--format=value(the.name.of.the.field)` is probably what you want. The trick is to know the name of the field. I usually start with `--format=json` on my development workstation to figure out the name.

Comment: This looks very good. I still have an issue "Step #5 - "Run vulneraibility scan": ERROR: (gcloud.beta.artifacts.docker.images.scan) Executable [local-extract] not found." and I see the same in CloudSheel. I suspect some issue with the latest version of GCD SDK. I will finish my tests and accept your anser.

Comment: right, using --format="value(response.scan)" allow me to extract the value. Thansk

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from Cloud Build. It cache some often used images and if you want to use a brand new feature in GCLOUD CLI the cache can be too old.

I performed a test tonight, the version is 326 in cache. the 328 has just been released. So, the cached version has 2 weeks old, maybe too old for your feature. It could be worse in your region!

The solution to fix this, is to explicitly request the latest version.

- Go to this url `gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud`
- Copy the latest version
  [image]
- Paste the full version name in the step of your Cloud Build pipeline.

The side effect is a longer build. Indeed, because this latest image isn't cached, it has to be downloaded in Cloud Build.

Comment: Thanks. It was found that the above tool (local-extract) is only working for MacOS and on Cloud Build we are facing similar issue:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/133389/no-such-file-or-directory-but-the-file-exists